# Finding combobox item

Tags: vb.net, combobox

For this question I made a simple class:

```
Public Class ListBoxEntry
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Text As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class
```

I create some instances of this class and add them into a combobox:

```
...
While DR.Read
  LI = New ListBoxEntry
  LI.ID = DR("ID") ' ID is an integer value
  LI.Text = DR(Feldname) ' Feldname is a string
  cmbList.Items.Add(LI)
End While
```

I cannot get a working code for setting the combobox to a specific value by code.
E.g. these are my three entries (ID - Feldname):

```
1 - One    (value 1, shown text in combobox "One")
2 - Two    (value 2, shown text in combobox "Two")
3 - Three  (value 3, shown text in combobox "Three")

Combobox1.SelectedIndex = somehow(2) <- here I want to set the combobox to the second entry (2), so "two" is selected
```

Which peace of code to I need?

Comment: You can obviously use whatever naming convention you want but why do you think you need that 'cls' prefix on that type name?  You use classes from the .NET Framework all the time with no such prefix so exactly what use does it serve?

Comment: I know - I added the cls thing just for this question and thought it would help. I won't do that again. Thank you for the hint

Comment: Given that the `Class` keyword is right before the class name in the declaration, it doesn't help.  Even without the declaration, people will generally assume that most types are classes, which absolutely should be the case, so you really only need to point out when something is a structure.  It often won't matter anyway but it can be critical, depending on the situation.

Comment: As said: You are right and thank you for clarifying that - I edited the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the instances of your class to an array or collection, then bind that to your `ComboBox`, e.g.

```
With ComboBox1
    .DisplayMember = "Text"
    .ValueMember = "ID"
    .DataSource = myList
End With
```

You can then assign an `ID` value to the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to select the item with that `ID`, e.g.

```
ComboBox.SelectedValue = 2
```

That would display "Two" in the control.